# Project targets platform version "8.1" but refrencing Windows 10 SDK

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, directx-11

I am trying to learn DirectX 11 in visual studio 2017 recently. So, I reached to [Introduction to C++ and DirectX Game Development Jump Start](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/introduction-to-c-and-directx-game-development-jump-start-8824), which was quite old. I downloaded the project from github, and tried to build on my Visual Studio 2017 community edition. Unfortunately, I failed to do so.
I even installed all the different SDKs from Visual Studio Installer 2017.

And yet I am unable to build the file as the output shows:-

> Project "SumoDX" targets platform version "8.1", but references SDK
>   "Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps v14.0"
>   which requires platform version "10.0.0.0" or higher.

Is there anything I am missing? I tried to change target platform but failed miserably.

Comment: Just retarget it to 10. "failed miserably" this needs explanation, post error message here.

Comment: I went to properties>configuration properties > General > Target platform. It is already set to 10. Changed the "Target platform version" and "Target platform minimum version " to 10.x.x.x. The above mentioned error got resolved.Thanks. But I am still getting error like *** namespace "Windows::Foundation" has no member "EventRegistrationToken" ***.How can it be resolved?  Also the "Platform Toolset" is set to "Visual Studio(v141) not installed". What does that mean?